# I am trying to delete a particular record but I get the following error message

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (23000)
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`project-management`.`projects`, CONSTRAINT `projects_company_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `companies` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `companies` where `id` = 2)

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete the record that have child relation ships.

In companies table record #2 is used as projects_company_id of projects table.

So, First delete the projects with company_id #2 and delete company with id #2.

Or

you can use ON DELETE CASCADE option for that constraint(like auto delete, Child records will automatically deletes when parent record deleted).